# Visually cloning a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, clone

I have a search box somewhere on top of my layout

```
<input type="text" id="rec_search_input" ...>
```

I want to *clone* this element to a second spot, it must look the same and behave the same.

Now I know an ID must be unique, but,.. imagine like a unix symlink, having the same file accessable from different directories.

Is it possible to clone a DOM element and reuse its attached styles + event handlers, ... ?

Comment: Did you not look at [jQuery's `clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proper solution would be to give the `.cloneNode()` a new ID, and only apply CSS to the element's class rather than its ID. So:

```
var clone = document.getElementById("rec_search_input").cloneNode();
clone.id = "some other id";
```

...and then append that elsewhere in the DOM (e.g., via `appendChild`, `insertBefore`, etc.). (Side note: Since your element is an `input`, it can't have children, but if you use this for other things, you can use `cloneNode(true)` to clone its descendant elements; then spin through them to be sure their `id` values are unique.)

To some extent, you can "cheat". ID uniqueness isn't enforced by the browser or anything, and CSS will apply to elements with the same ID even if there are more than one. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/577j8/)

However, as you are probably aware, JavaScript functions like `getElementById` will not work predictably if you have duplicate IDs.

Comment: The problem is, I should have mentioned this, there is about 2k Javascript lines attached to the search box id, several files, several ajax requests, tracking, recommendations, typeahead, ...